# Minifying the conditional statement used in the comments of HTML using gulp

Tags: gulp

I want to minify the following HTML code. I am using the gulp-cleanhtml which works fine for me except the following mentioned criteria:

it does not minify the Styles of HTML conditional statements. Check the below code:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style> 
sup 
   {   
     font-size:100% !important;
   }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Can anyone guide me how to go about? So that I can minify the code within those conditional statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gulp-htmlmin` should get you there with the following options:

```
.pipe(
    htmlmin({
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        processConditionalComments: true,
    })
)
```

which should result in:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><style>sup{font-size:100%!important}</style><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Made one correction from `minifyCss` to `minifyCSS`

Comment: Thank you so much! this was really helpful.